# How to handle click event on notification in android (FCM) when app is in background or killed?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to handle a click operation on notification when application is
 in background or killed, for redirecting application to notification details screen. I can handle it when there is only one notification in the **Notification tray** by using the **Default Activity** defined in manifest file.

But the problem is when there are two or more notifications in the **Notification tray**, how i can identify which notification is clicked..?

Please help

Comment: Well, you must be providing `notificationId` in `notify()`. You can use it to identify notification. Though you have to provide unique id for each notification.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Wizard, can you please tell me about method **notify()**?

Comment: `mNotificationManager.notify(_notificationId, mBuilder.build());` - you can use `_notificationId` to identify nofication in a unique way.

Comment: Many Thanks @Wizard,I will try this.

Comment: @Wizard it worked  for me i used notificationId and checked it in the extras() of defaultActivity.. Thanks a lot